# PHP Session Array Copy

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, pdo

I have 2 pages. Page 1 is for user data input and page 2 is kind of like a confirmation of sorts. I have a php file called insert.php whose sole job is to insert data into the mysql table with data from page 1. So on page2 i copy the $_POST array that contains all the data from page 1 into a session. Here it is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#PaySubmit").click(function() {
        alert("done");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Insert.php'
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php 
session_start();
$prev_url1 = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],-18);
$_SESSION = array_merge($_POST);
?>

<form id="pay" name="pay" method="post" action="RandomPage.php">
<input type="submit" name="PaySubmit" id="PaySubmit" value="Continue"/>
</form>
```

In Insert, here's the code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
try {
    $link = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=;charset=UTF-8','','');
    $gid = $link->prepare("SELECT MAX(Group_ID) as maxGroup FROM Conference");
    $gid->execute();
    $groupid = $gid->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $groupid = $groupid['maxGroup']+1;
    $regisid = $groupid;
    $first = $_SESSION["fname"];
    $last = $_SESSION["lname"];
    $addr = $_SESSION["address"];
    $city = $_SESSION["city"];
    $state = $_SESSION["state"];

    $stmt = $link -> prepare("INSERT INTO Conference (`Registrar_ID`, `Group_ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Address`, `City`, `State`) VALUES (:regisid, :groupid, :first, :last, :addr, :city, :state)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':regisid', $regisid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':groupid', $groupid);
        $stmt->bindParam(':first', $first);
        $stmt->bindParam(':last', $last);
        $stmt->bindParam(':addr', $addr);
        $stmt->bindParam(':city', $city);
        $stmt->bindParam(':state', $state);

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
?>
```

But for some reason this just won't get inserted. Before I just had all the insert code in the 2nd page and it worked perfectly, but i wanted it to only insert if they clicked submit on the 2nd page which is why i had to do this. Why doesn't this work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think there's a lot wrong with this code.. so far I can see that you're using `array_merge` to do nothing at all and you're not giving the `PDO` constructor any hostname, database, username or password...

Comment: Is there more going on here than you've posted? There is no reason to use jquery the way your example is set up...just add the desired page to the forms action and let the submit button do its thing

Comment: @Erik nope the merge is fine. Thoroughly tested it it, the $_SESSION becomes an exact copy of $_POST                                                                to user1026361: Can't because posting from the 2nd page would mean all the data from the 1st page would be lost which is why i'm using sessions

Comment: @Richard yes it's fine but it doesn't do anything at all... `$_SESSION = $_POST;` is the same as `$_SESSION = array_merge($_POST);`

Comment: @Erik ah okay fixed now. But i can't figure out why this code won't work. I even echoed `$_SESSION["fname"]` on insert.php and it printed the correct value. So I don't understand why it won't insert.

Comment: @Richard what's the error message you're getting? check `print_r($_SESSION)`. are all keys correct? Also I still do not see `$stmt->execute()`...

Comment: @Erik yah i did `var_dump($_SESSION)`, everything is correct. I actually also did `var_dump($_POST)` and they both look the exact same. Sorry forgot to edit post, will do now.

Comment: do you have enabled error reporting? add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of both pages, and check for any errors

Comment: @VladBalmos put those in and no problems reported.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing

```
$stmt->execute()
```

Comment: no sorry i forgot to copy that part from the code. I had an execute. Edited original post.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` must be called before echoing anything to the browser

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#PaySubmit").click(function() {
        alert("done");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Insert.php'
        });
    });
});
</script>
<?php 
$prev_url1 = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],-18);
$_SESSION = array_merge($_POST);
?>

<form id"pay" name="pay" method="post" action="RandomPage.php">
<input type="submit" name="PaySubmit" id="PaySubmit" value="Continue"/>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**
Is your insert file called Insert.php or insert.php? case matters on linux systems

Comment: it is uppercase, Insert.php. I think I found the problem, when i put the forms action to be `action="Insert.php"` it worked. But i don't want it to go there...i thought that the ajax call was the work around for that but maybe i have my syntax wrong or something.